# Angular-UI multiple datepickers insider form controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am creating a form with multiple angular-ui datepickers and some input data.
For the datepickers I have created a controller and a parent form controller like the sample given below. The form controller has the model which includes the datepicker dates.

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('dateCntrl', function($scope,$timeout){
    $scope.open = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.opened = true;
        });
    };
});

app.controller('formCntrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.model = {name:'', startDate:'', endDate:''};
});
```

HTML:

```
<form ng-controller="formCntrl">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="model.name" />
    <div ng-controller="dateCntrl">
        <input datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy"  ng-model="model.startDate" id="startDate" type="text" />
        <button class="btn" ng-click="open()"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="dateCntrl">
        <input datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="model.endDate" id="endDate" type="text" />
        <button class="btn" ng-click="open()"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

- Am I going the right way in having a separate controller for the datepicker. This will act as a common controller for all the date inputs
- If yes, is it possible to have a generic way of binding the data in the datepicker controller back to the model dates(model.startDate,model.endDate in this case) in the parent controller.
- Is there a alternative way to go about this.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Should have read more about the [scope inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

The parent scope values can be accessed using $parent

```
<form ng-controller="formCntrl">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="model.name" />
    <div ng-controller="dateCntrl">
        <input datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy"  ng-model="$parent.model.startDate" id="startDate" type="text" />
        <button class="btn" ng-click="open()"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="dateCntrl">
        <input datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="$parent.model.endDate" id="endDate" type="text" />
        <button class="btn" ng-click="open()"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out as both pickers where opening at the same time .. for me it's: $parent.startDate (btw you actually only need to use ng-controller/$parent on one of the 2 pickers so they don't interfere with another ..but i suppose readability-wise it's probably best to annotate both)

Answer (score 4):

I took all the code from the verbose example here: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker & wrapped it into my own directive. This way I can just drop unlimited datepickers into my page, and specify the model for each one to bind to. I do not have to manage passing repetitive settings, or setting up unique variables for tracking the "open" status anymore, I just put 1 line of code:

```
<div my-date-picker my-date-picker-model="myDate1"></div>
<div my-date-picker my-date-picker-model="myDate2"></div>
<div my-date-picker my-date-picker-model="myDate3"></div>
```

The user can then toggle each date picker open/closed, and the values will be updated into `myDate1`, `myDate2`, & `myDate3` appropriately. The open/closed status is now encapsulated within the directive, and out of mind.

To implement the directive, I copied the 'JS' tab's code into it's controller, and I copied the 'Markup' tab's code into it's template. At the end I added 1 bit of code to update the value to the parent scope:

```
$scope.$watch('dt', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    $scope.myDatePickerModel = newVal;
});
```

At the start of the controller, I changed $scope.today to initialize the value from the parent scope, instead of using the system clock:

```
$scope.init = function() {
    $scope.dt = $scope.hxDatePickerModel;
};
$scope.init();
```

The directive uses an isolate scope, and 2-way binding on the attribute which defines the parent scope's model:

```
scope: {
    myDatePickerModel: '='
}
```

Here's the full code of the directive:

```
app.directive('myDatePicker', function() {

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    }

    function controller($scope) {
       $scope.init = function() {
        $scope.dt = $scope.myDatePickerModel;
    };
    $scope.init();

        $scope.clear = function () {
            $scope.dt = null;
        };

        // Disable weekend selection
        $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
            return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
        };

        $scope.toggleMin = function() {
            $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
        };
        $scope.toggleMin();

        $scope.open = function($event) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();

            $scope.opened = true;
        };

        $scope.dateOptions = {
            formatYear: 'yy',
            startingDay: 1
        };

        $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
        $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];

    $scope.$watch('dt', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        $scope.myDatePickerModel = newVal;
    });

    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'datepicker.html',
        link: link,
        controller: controller,
        scope: {
            myDatePickerModel: '='
        }
    }
});
```

And here is the full code of `datepicker.html`, the template for this directive:

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
      </span>
</p>
```

Comment: I use your directive right now, it works like a charme. However, I'm unable to clear the selected date from the view-controller (the view where the directive is used). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

other solution , declare  the datepicker's open() method in $rootScope and it is available  entire  application .

Html :

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="DemoController">

        <div> 
        <input  type="text" name="salesEndDate" id = "salesEndDate"   datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy"  ng-model="salesEndDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions"/>
        <button id="salesEndDateCal" ng-click="datePickerOpen('salesEndDate')"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button> 
        </div>

    <div>
        <input  type="text" name="salesStartDate" id = "salesStartDate"   datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy"  ng-model="salesStartDate"  datepicker-options="dateOptions"/>
         <button id="salesEndDateCal" ng-click="datePickerOpen('salesStartDate')"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button> 
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.bootstrap','ui.bootstrap.datepicker']);


function DemoController($scope,$timeout,$rootScope) { 


$rootScope.datePickerOpen = function(id) {

             $timeout(function() {
                    $("#"+id).focus(); 
                });      
         };
}
```

jsfiddle link  http://jsfiddle.net/angles_k/s7yZm/21/